# jdbctemplate SQL with where condition containing IN clause and other parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, informix, jdbctemplate

```sql
SELECT *
  from order_details
 where store_nbr = ?
   and div_nbr = ?
   and ordered_item = ?
   and message_code not in(%s)
   and DATE(order_date) = DATE(?)
```

Here I have to pass individual parameters and an array of `message_code` in one Spring Boot application.
How can I achieve this by jdbcTemplate or by any other means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list

Comment: Thanks Henning. But the query have  'in' clause and other parameters(4 parameters). How can we pass all these together?

Comment: Got the solution, pass the individual parameters directly to the query and the 'in' clause params as a array